# Move view in direction of specific angle

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uianimation

I have an angle that I am calculating based on the positioning of a view from the centre of the screen. I need a way to move the view from it's current position, off the screen in the direction of the angle.

I'm sure there is a fairly simple way of calculating a new x and y value, but I haven't been able to figure out the maths. I want to do it using an animation, but I can figure that out myself once I have the coordinates.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have angle you can calculate new coordinates by getting sine and cosine values. You can try out following code

```
let pathLength = 50 as Double // total distance view should move
let piFactor = M_PI / 180
let angle = 90 as Double // direction in which you need to move it
let xCoord = outView.frame.origin.x +  CGFloat(pathLength * sin(piFactor*angle)) //outView is name of view you want to animate
let yCoord = outView.frame.origin.y +  CGFloat(pathLength * cos(piFactor*angle))
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.outView.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, self.outView.frame.size.width, self.outView.frame.size.height)
        }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
})
```

Comment: This works great. Only issue is it moves the view in the direction that it has been dragged from the centre, however (as I should have mentioned), I need it to move in the opposite direction. The view acts a bit like a slingshot, so as you pull it in one direction, it should fly back across the view and off the screen.

Comment: Update: I found that the issue was with the code I already have. Everything works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds what you need to do is convert a vector from polar representation (angle and radius) to cartesian representation (x and y coordinates) which should be fairly easy. 
You already got the angle so you only need to get the radius, which is the length of the vector. In you case (if I understand it correctly) is the distance from the current center of the view that needs to be animated to it's new position. While it may be complex to know that exactly (cause this part of what you are trying to calculate) you can go on the safe side and take a large enough value that will surely throw the view out of its super view frame. The length of the superview diagonal plus the length of the animated view diagonal should do the work, or even more simple just take the sum of the height and width of both views.

Once you have the complete polar representation of the vector (angle and radius) you can use [that simple formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) to convert to cartesian representation (x = r * cos(a), y = r * sin(a)) and finally add that vector coordinates to the center of the view you need to animate.